# How to give the result of a query in a subtitution variable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

sequel from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72471845/how-to-use-a-sql-plus-variable-when-calling-a-script)

this SQL plus code is working

```
define a=22; 
host powershell.exe echo &a;
```

> 22

But if the value from a comes from a query, it doesn't work anymore.

```
define a=2; 
select 22 into a;
host powershell.exe echo &a;
```

> 2  instead of 22

I've tried that with a buffer but to no avails

```
variable buffer varchar2;
select 22 into :buffer from dual;
define a=b;
host powershell.exe echo &a;
```

> :b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`column .. new_value ...` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/COLUMN.html#d25893e883). If you still want a bind variable too, as in your previous question, then define and populate that variable however you are now, e.g.:

```
SQL> variable buffer varchar2(2);
SQL> exec :buffer := '22';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print buffer

BUFFER
--------------------------------
22
```

Then define the column with a new value you can refer to later as a substitution variable:

```
SQL> column a new_value a
SQL> select :buffer as a from dual;

A
--------------------------------
22

SQL> host powershell.exe echo &a
22

SQL>
```

You can `set termout off` and back on around that extra query if you're running this as a script and don't want to see the output.

And you can query anything, it doesn't have to be a bind variable:

```
select 22 as a from dual;
```

or

```
SQL> select sysdate as a from dual;

A
---------
02-JUN-22

SQL> host powershell.exe echo &a
02-JUN-22

SQL>
```