# How to print with powershell from SQLplus a string with quotation quotes

Tags: oracle, powershell, sqlplus

Sequel from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72471845/how-to-use-a-sql-plus-variable-when-calling-a-script)

```
define a='eee"dd'
prompt &a                       -- eee"dd OK
host powershell.exe echo '&a';  -- eeedd  not OK
host powershell.exe echo &a;    -- eeedd  not OK
```

As you can see, I can't print a stirng with a quotation quote in powershell from sql plus.
Is there a way to do that.?

---

I've tried the solution of Alex Poole when the value comes from a query.But it's not working if there is more than one quotation string.

```
column a new_value a 
select replace('eee"d"d', '"', '""') as a from dual;

prompt &a                      -- eee""d""d  Ok as expected
host powershell.exe echo '"&a"'-- eee"dd instead of eee"d"d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you escape the quote ([for PowerShell's benefit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2)) by using `""` within the value, *and* use both types of quotes, for both PowerShell's and SQL*Plus's benefit:

```
SQL> define a='eee""dd'
SQL> host powershell.exe echo '"&a"'
eee"dd
```

If you are actually populating the `a` variable from a query, as in your previous questions, then you can `replace()` quotes with:

```
column a new_value a
select replace('eee"dd', '"', '""') as a from dual;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I's not working if I use more than one quotation quote. I've given a exemple in my question.

Comment: That seems to be a PowerShell issue... from the command line, one of their sample strings `"As they say, ""live and learn."""` works, but not with anything between the 'real' closing quote and the string-ending quote, even a space, e.g. `"As they say, ""live and learn."" "`.

Comment: _Without_ `cmd.exe` in the picture, the robust way to escape `"` chars. for the PowerShell CLI with the (possibly implied) `-Command` parameter is to use `\"`. _With_ `cmd.exe` in the picture, this may break _situationally_, and the workaround depends on the edition of PowerShell you use - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).

Answer (score 1):

```
column a new_value a
select replace('eee"d"d', '"', '\"') as a from dual;
host powershell.exe echo '&a'
```

works for me